# What these hex values mean in this font binary

Tags: debugging, fonts, binary, hex, byte

I am working on compiling a font and have been running into some errors. I am learning how to debug binaries with the hex viewer but it is still new to me.

Wondering what some of these numbers mean:

```
00000000: 4f54 544f 0009 0008 0003 0001 4346 4632  OTTO........CFF2
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 00c2 9c00 0000 1063 6d61  .............cma
00000020: 7000 0000 0000 0000 c2ac 0000 0024 6865  p............$he
00000030: 6164 0000 0000 0000 00c3 9000 0000 3668  ad............6h
00000040: 6865 6100 0000 0000 0001 0800 0000 2468  hea...........$h
00000050: 6d74 7800 0000 0000 0001 2c00 0000 006d  mtx.......,....m
00000060: 6178 7000 0000 0000 0001 2c00 0000 066e  axp.......,....n
00000070: 616d 6500 0000 0000 0001 3400 0000 064f  ame.......4....O
00000080: 532f 3200 0000 0000 0001 3c00 0000 6470  S/2.......<...dp
00000090: 6f73 7400 0000 0000 0001 c2a0 0000 0020  ost............
000000a0: 00c2 b400 c384 00c3 a800 0001 1e01 4201  ..............B.
000000b0: 4200 0001 4800 0001 4e01 c2b2 0200 0400  B...H...N.......
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001  ................
000000d0: 0000 0006 0000 0010 0004 0010 0000 0002  ................
000000e0: 0002 0000 0000 c3bf c3bf 0000 c3bf c3bf  ................
000000f0: 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 5f0f 3cc3 b500 0303 c3a8 0000 0000 c398  _.<.............
00000110: 65c2 98c3 8a00 0000 00c3 9865 c298 c38a  e..........e....
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0003 0002 0000  ................
00000130: 0000 0001 0000 00c3 8800 6400 0000 0000  ..........d.....
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0050 0000 0000 0000  .........P......
00000160: 0000 0600 0500 0000 0000 0000 0002 c28a  ................
00000170: 02c2 bb00 0000 c28c 02c2 8a02 c2bb 0000  ................
00000180: 01c3 9f00 3101 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....1...........
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001a0: 0000 0058 5858 5800 0000 0000 0000 0000  ...XXXX.........
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0300  ................
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00         .............
```

Specifically I'm wondering, why they aren't showing up on the right side as some integer or something. I am wondering how that stuff on the right shows up, if it is just "luck" that it shows up or there is some system to it where I could learn more about it.

Basically I have this data structure that gets *serialized* into this binary:

```
{
  "name": "sfnt",
  "fields": {
    "scalar": {
      "type": "TAG",
      "value": "OTTO"
    },
    "numTables": {
      "type": "USHORT",
      "value": 9
    },
    "searchRange": {
      "type": "USHORT",
      "value": 8
    },
    "entrySelector": {
      "type": "USHORT",
      "value": 3
    },
    "rangeShift": {
      "type": "USHORT",
      "value": 1
    },
    "CFF2 Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "CFF2"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 156
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 16
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cmap Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "cmap"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 172
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 36
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "head Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "head"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 208
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 54
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hhea Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "hhea"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 264
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 36
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hmtx Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "hmtx"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 300
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "maxp Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "maxp"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 300
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 6
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "name Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "name"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 308
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 6
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "OS/2 Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "OS/2"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 316
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 100
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "post Table Record": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "Table Record",
        "fields": {
          "tag": {
            "type": "TAG",
            "value": "post"
          },
          "checkSum": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 416
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 32
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "CFF2 table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "CFF2",
        "fields": {
          "header": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "Header",
              "fields": {
                "major": {
                  "type": "BYTE",
                  "value": 2
                },
                "minor": {
                  "type": "BYTE",
                  "value": 0
                },
                "hdrSize": {
                  "type": "BYTE",
                  "value": 4
                },
                "topDictLength": {
                  "type": "USHORT",
                  "value": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "nameIndex": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "Name INDEX",
              "fields": {
                "names": {
                  "type": "INDEX",
                  "value": []
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "topDictIndex": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "Top DICT INDEX",
              "fields": {
                "topDicts": {
                  "type": "INDEX",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "name": "topDict_0",
                      "type": "TABLE",
                      "value": {}
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "stringIndex": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "String INDEX",
              "fields": {
                "strings": {
                  "type": "INDEX",
                  "value": []
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "globalSubrIndex": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "Global Subr INDEX",
              "fields": {
                "subrs": {
                  "type": "INDEX",
                  "value": []
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "charsets": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "Charsets",
              "fields": {
                "format": {
                  "type": "Card8",
                  "value": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "charStringsIndex": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "CharStrings INDEX",
              "fields": {
                "charStrings": {
                  "type": "INDEX",
                  "value": []
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "privateDict": {
            "type": "RECORD",
            "value": {
              "name": "Private DICT",
              "fields": {
                "dict": {
                  "type": "DICT",
                  "value": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cmap table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "cmap",
        "fields": {
          "version": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "numTables": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 1
          },
          "platformID": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "encodingID": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 6
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 16
          },
          "format": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 4
          },
          "cmap4Length": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 16
          },
          "language": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "segCountX2": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 2
          },
          "searchRange": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 2
          },
          "entrySelector": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "rangeShift": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "end_0": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 65535
          },
          "reservedPad": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "start_0": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 65535
          },
          "idDelta_0": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 1
          },
          "idRangeOffset_0": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "head table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "head",
        "fields": {
          "version": {
            "type": "FIXED",
            "value": 65536
          },
          "fontRevision": {
            "type": "FIXED",
            "value": 65536
          },
          "checkSumAdjustment": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "magicNumber": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 1594834165
          },
          "flags": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 3
          },
          "unitsPerEm": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 1000
          },
          "created": {
            "type": "LONGDATETIME",
            "value": 3630534741
          },
          "modified": {
            "type": "LONGDATETIME",
            "value": 3630534741
          },
          "xMin": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": null
          },
          "yMin": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": null
          },
          "xMax": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": null
          },
          "yMax": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": null
          },
          "macStyle": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "lowestRecPPEM": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 3
          },
          "fontDirectionHint": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 2
          },
          "indexToLocFormat": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "glyphDataFormat": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "padding_0": {
      "type": "BYTE",
      "value": 0
    },
    "padding_1": {
      "type": "BYTE",
      "value": 0
    },
    "hhea table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "hhea",
        "fields": {
          "version": {
            "type": "FIXED",
            "value": 65536
          },
          "ascender": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": 200
          },
          "descender": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": 100
          },
          "lineGap": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": 0
          },
          "advanceWidthMax": {
            "type": "UFWORD",
            "value": null
          },
          "minLeftSideBearing": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": null
          },
          "minRightSideBearing": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": null
          },
          "xMaxExtent": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": null
          },
          "caretSlopeRise": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 1
          },
          "caretSlopeRun": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "caretOffset": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "reserved1": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "reserved2": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "reserved3": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "reserved4": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "metricDataFormat": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "numberOfHMetrics": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hmtx table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "hmtx",
        "fields": {}
      }
    },
    "maxp table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "maxp",
        "fields": {
          "version": {
            "type": "FIXED",
            "value": 20480
          },
          "numGlyphs": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "padding_2": {
      "type": "BYTE",
      "value": 0
    },
    "padding_3": {
      "type": "BYTE",
      "value": 0
    },
    "name table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "name",
        "fields": {
          "format": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "count": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "stringOffset": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 6
          },
          "strings": {
            "type": "LITERAL",
            "value": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "padding_4": {
      "type": "BYTE",
      "value": 0
    },
    "padding_5": {
      "type": "BYTE",
      "value": 0
    },
    "OS/2 table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "OS/2",
        "fields": {
          "version": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 5
          },
          "xAvgCharWidth": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usWeightClass": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usWidthClass": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "fsType": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ySubscriptXSize": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 650
          },
          "ySubscriptYSize": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 699
          },
          "ySubscriptXOffset": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ySubscriptYOffset": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 140
          },
          "ySuperscriptXSize": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 650
          },
          "ySuperscriptYSize": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 699
          },
          "ySuperscriptXOffset": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ySuperscriptYOffset": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 479
          },
          "yStrikeoutSize": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 49
          },
          "yStrikeoutPosition": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 258
          },
          "sFamilyClass": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bFamilyType": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bSerifStyle": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bWeight": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bProportion": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bContrast": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bStrokeVariation": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bArmStyle": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bLetterform": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bMidline": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "bXHeight": {
            "type": "BYTE",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ulUnicodeRange1": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ulUnicodeRange2": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ulUnicodeRange3": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ulUnicodeRange4": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "achVendID": {
            "type": "CHARARRAY",
            "value": "XXXX"
          },
          "fsSelection": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usFirstCharIndex": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usLastCharIndex": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "sTypoAscender": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "sTypoDescender": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "sTypoLineGap": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usWinAscent": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usWinDescent": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ulCodePageRange1": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "ulCodePageRange2": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "sxHeight": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "sCapHeight": {
            "type": "SHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usDefaultChar": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usBreakChar": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usMaxContext": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usLowerOpticalPointSize": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          },
          "usUpperOpticalPointSize": {
            "type": "USHORT",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "post table": {
      "type": "RECORD",
      "value": {
        "name": "post",
        "fields": {
          "version": {
            "type": "FIXED",
            "value": 196608
          },
          "italicAngle": {
            "type": "FIXED",
            "value": 0
          },
          "underlinePosition": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": 0
          },
          "underlineThickness": {
            "type": "FWORD",
            "value": 0
          },
          "isFixedPitch": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "minMemType42": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "maxMemType42": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "minMemType1": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          },
          "maxMemType1": {
            "type": "ULONG",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially all the `value` fields get concatenated, *after some slight modification during serialization*. So that's where errors could be coming in, which I want to look into.

I got this far now, by removing `toArrayBuffer` stuff and just doing `write(new Buffer(bytes))`, giving:

```
00000000: 4f54 544f 0009 0008 0003 0001 4346 4632  OTTO........CFF2
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 009c 0000 0010 636d 6170  ............cmap
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 00ac 0000 0024 6865 6164  ...........$head
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 00d0 0000 0036 6868 6561  ...........6hhea
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0108 0000 0024 686d 7478  ...........$hmtx
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 012c 0000 0000 6d61 7870  .......,....maxp
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 012c 0000 0006 6e61 6d65  .......,....name
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0134 0000 0006 4f53 2f32  .......4....OS/2
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 013c 0000 0064 706f 7374  .......<...dpost
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 01a0 0000 0020 0200 0400  ........... ....
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001  ................
000000b0: 0000 0006 0000 0010 0004 0010 0000 0002  ................
000000c0: 0002 0000 0000 ffff 0000 ffff 0001 0000  ................
000000d0: 0001 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 5f0f 3cf5  ............_.<.
000000e0: 0003 03e8 0000 0000 d865 b0f5 0000 0000  .........e......
000000f0: d865 b0f5 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0003  .e..............
00000100: 0002 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 00c8 0064  ...............d
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 5000  ..............P.
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0006 0000 0005 0000  ................
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 028a 02bb 0000 008c 028a  ................
00000150: 02bb 0000 01df 0031 0102 0000 0000 0000  .......1........
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 5858 5858 0000 0000 0000  ......XXXX......
00000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001a0: 0003 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

But now it's giving me (after adding some glyphs):

```
OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to serialize table
```

Not sure what is the best approach from here.

Comment: It will be easier for people to provide useful answers if you post the code (_full_ code, not single statements) that performs the serialization from your data structure into the font binary. It's very difficult to accurately diagnose what's going wrong in your code when we only see the inputs and outputs.

Comment: _"I'm wondering, why they aren't showing up on the right side"_ – the right side shows the corresponding ASCII character (e.g. `O` for `0x4F`, `T` for `0x54` and so on) or `.` if the byte isn't a printable ASCII character (like `0x00` or `0x09`). It helps you to read and identify text within the data.